# Any image picker with icloud image downloading support, like whatsapp?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, icloud, elcimagepickercontroller

I have searched for multi select imagepicker libraries that can start downloading images and video that are in icloud and not locally store, like whatsapp does. 
I can write my own patch in https://cocoapods.org/pods/ELCImagePickerController. But I think its not a rare requirement or feature. So I believe there must be some work done for this feature. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Asking for a third party library is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ohk, thanks for the info, didnt know that. 
Still if someone has faced this issue, it will be a fruitful conversation for the community.

Comment: https://github.com/guillermomuntaner/GMImagePicker does the download if phasset is in icloud with the indicator on each item. 
Limitation: it only supports images only. I have added the support for the videos, will create a PR soon.

Comment: https://github.com/MubeenQazi/GMImagePickerWithCloudMediaDownloading 
Might be helpful for someone.